# MDL upgradeElement / upgradeDom not working

Tags: javascript, element, upgrade, material-design-lite

I've got the following HTML code:

```
<div class="mailTabs mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
<a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">TAB1</a>
<a href="#scroll-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">TAB2</a>
<a href="#scroll-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">TAB3</a>
</div>
```

When the page is loaded each tab looks like this:
`<a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab">TAB1<span class="mdl-layout__tab-ripple-container mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-upgraded=",MaterialRipple">` etc.

When I try to add some extra tabs dynamically,they won't receive the same classes and additional stuff to make them look like my 'original hardcoded tabs'.

My code to dynamically add a tab is as follows:

```
var tabElement ='<a href="#scroll-tab-4" class="mdl-layout__tab"></a>';
$(tabElement).appendTo($('.mailTabs'));
```

I tried using `componentHandler.upgradeDom(); or componentHandler.upgradeElement('MaterialTabs','mdl-js-tabs');` but nothing seems to update my dynamically added elements.

What have I missed?

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9sv1fb19/)

Comment: what exactly are you looking for when you say: "they won't receive the same classes and additional stuff to make them look like my 'original hardcoded tabs'" ? what are that classes? `mdl-layout__tab` or something else?

Comment: @SimonBaars, unfortunately, adding a bounty to this question is not enough to solve its problems. First of all, it doesn't have a clear reproducible case. The fiddle seems to suffer from an internal bug in the included library (click a tab to repro). Linking a more recent version of the lib might fix that. Second of all, the expected output is not clearly defined. We don't know what *"nothing seems to update my dynamically added elements"* actually means. Possibly related: [Adding tab dynamically upgradeElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563950/)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old jQuery code but it works. It creates the tab but it's not visible. You can see it if you add:

```
TAB4
```

As inner text of the tag

```
<a>
```

This is the line only with the **TAB4** change:

```
var tabElement ='<a href="#scroll-tab-4" class="mdl-layout__tab">TAB4</a>';
```