# Adding tab dynamically upgradeElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design-lite

When I add a tab with react, its parent element is already upgraded. So calling upgradElement has no effect and the added tab doesn't work.
What solution, recreate all tabs with the container and upgrade it ? React just update DOM component in this case I need to dismount component ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about calling componentHandler.upgradeElement() or componentHandler.upgradeDom() in the componentDidUpdate phase of the specific component

```js
    componentDidUpdate() {
        componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.refs.myElement);
        //or componentHandler.upgradeDom('MaterialTabs');
    }
```

**EDIT 1 Tab Component**

```js
    componentDidUpdate() {

        componentHandler.upgradeDom();
    }

    newTab() {
        this.setState({
            newtab: 1
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (<div className="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header" key={this.state.newtab}>
            <button onClick={this.newTab.bind(this)}>Add Tab</button>
                <header className="mdl-layout__header">
                    <div className="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                        <Link to="/tabtest" hash="#scroll-tab-1" className="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Tab 1</Link>
                        <Link to="/tabtest" hash="#scroll-tab-2" className="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 2</Link>
                        { this.state.newtab ?
                        <Link to="/tabtest" hash="#scroll-tab-3" className="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 3</Link> : null}
                    </div>
                </header>
            <div className="mdl-layout__content">
                <section className="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="scroll-tab-1">
                    <div className="page-content">Tab 1</div>
                </section>
                <section className="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-2">
                    <div className="page-content">Tab 2</div>
                </section>
                { this.state.newtab ? <section className="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-3">
                    <div className="page-content">Tab 2</div>
                </section> : null}
            </div>
        </div>);

    }
```

I did some tests and could reproduce the problem. What helped was to put the key attribute on the root element of the tab component. When adding a new tab this key must change and react will throw away the component and rerender completly. This way all material-design-lite properties get lost and after calling upgradeDom or upgradeElement it works.

[React and Material-Design-Lite](http://quaintous.com/2015/07/09/react-components-with-mdl/)

[Material-Design-Lite source](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/v1.0.6/material.js#L42)

Comment: That's what I did, calling componentHandler.upgradeDom() but it do nothing because I think that TabContainer is already upgrade so it don't go deep in the dom. I'll try to upgradeElement the specific tab...

Comment: In fact tabs element are not ugradable element this is the div container that is ugradable and it is already upgraded. So I don't know how to force upgradeElement.

Comment: Ok then you have to use forceUpdate on the tabcontainer when you add a tab and then call this.upgradeElement. I will try myself also.

Comment: I don't need to forceUpdate, DOM is update but after upgradeElement don't do the job, I try to downgrade and upgrade after but it still don't work.

Comment: Updated my answer, got it to work. I hope it helps you to go on.

Answer (score 0):

From https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html.

forceUpdate

void forceUpdate(
  [function callback]
)

By default, when your component's state or props change, your component will re-render. However, if these change implicitly (eg: data deep within an object changes without changing the object itself) or if your render() method depends on some other data, you can tell React that it needs to re-run render() by calling forceUpdate().

Calling forceUpdate() will cause render() to be called on the component, skipping shouldComponentUpdate(). This will trigger the normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the shouldComponentUpdate() method of each child. React will still only update the DOM if the markup changes.

Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your component "pure" and your application much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: I agree but react update the dom but MDL had upgrade it, so new tab is render but the MDL tab container is already flag has upgraded so the new tab does't work well. I need to recreate the all the component dom to its initial state (before MDL upgrade).

Comment: I think I need to downgrade the DOM in componentWillUnmount function. MDL has function to do this ?

Comment: I don't use MDL so would not know.

Answer (score 0):

In order to highlight the most important part of Christian Steinmann's answer:

Give the surrounding `.mdl-js-tabs` div element the tabs count as the `key` attribute.

Whenever a tab is added, the key will change and React will rerender the whole tabs component. This will then the MDL upgrade.